# JSP to Servlet, back to textarea of same JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have been working on a simple problem for quite a long time. Searched a lot in many forums including this site, but still couldn't solve this particular issue. Hence asking for your favor.

I have a JSP page with a textarea and a submit button.

```
<%@page language="java" session="true" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form name="test" action="/servlet/Servlet" method="post" >
Output:<br />
  <textarea name="output" style="width:100%" rows="40"  value="${result}" />
  </textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In the Servlet class I am doing the following -

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    try
    {
    request.setAttribute("result","output text from servlet");

    String nextJSP = "/test.jsp"; 
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP); 
    dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

So after I am clicking the submit button, my request is going to the servlet and from servlet I am back to the original jsp, but I am not able to populate the textarea with the servlet output. I have tried in many ways as I found in the internet, like ${requestScope.result}, but none of them were able to populate the textarea! Can you please suggest? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textarea tags are different from input tags. You don't use a value attribute. You put the value between the opening and closing textarea tags.

```
<textarea name="output" style="width:100%" rows="40">${result}</textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I did it.